# Multiple Filter in Same Component.html

Tags: angular

is it possible to reference from first filter to second filter. I mean using **item.subject** instead of **'lifestyle'**. So that i can get the output of the first filter and use it to as an argument in the second filter.

```
<div class="jumbotron" >
  <h1>Story Info</h1> 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let item of data | filter : id" #val > {{item.subject}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Related Stories</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let story of data | storyCategory : 'lifestyle' " > {{story.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>enter code hereenter code here
```

Comment: certainly possible. What is the output that comes from the filter? a user modified one or iterated one

Comment: iterated one. I tried to use; storyCategory : '{{item.subject}}' or 'item.subject'. Neither of them worked. I get this error; **Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined**